# Set default value for optional nested object with setter in orElse clasue

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, java-11

I want to check the value of an Adapter class which is nested object in Device class which looks like:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Device {
    private Optional<Socket> socket;
}
```

Socket looks like:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Socket {
    private Optional<Adapter> adapter = Optional.empty();
}
```

Adapter looks like:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Adapter {
    public String name;
}
```

and in case that it will be empty set a default value for a field `name`.

My method looks like:

```
public static Optional<Adapter> checkAdapterNameOrSetDefaultValue(Optional<Device> device) {
return device
        .flatMap(Device::getSocket)
        .ifPresent(d -> d.getAdapter().orElse(d.setAdapter(Optional.of(new Adapter("DDD")))));
}
```

Seemingly, it could work but IntelliJ complain about the  setter part which is void:

```
d.setAdapter(Optional.of(new Adapter("DDD")))
```

with a message:

```
orElse Adapter in Optional cannot be applied to (void)
```

Here the question arises whether it is possible to cast the void type on Optional in this case so that the types are compatible with each other or set the default name in a different way.

Comment: It's not IntelliJ, but Java compiler itself complaining. `orElse` expects a value (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) and your setter function doesn't return anything, not even `Void` (`Void` class and `void` keyword are two different things). Instead, just try passing this `Optional.of(new Adapter("DDD"))` to `orElse`.

Comment: Well, your function looks a little odd. You're getting the device's adapter _and_ are setting one in case it is empty - I'd call that an unexpected side effect. I'd suggest you split those 2 things and then it should be easier to set a new adapter if one is missing.

Comment: @SachithDickwella I wasn't precise in my words, I just preferred to illustrate a simple IntelliJ message. I will check your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed a couple of problems here.

1. You misuse `Optional` by having `Optional` fields.
2. You misuse `Optional` by passing it as a method argument.
3. `checkAdapterNameOrSetDefaultValue` sounds like a `void` method. Neither `check` nor `set` implies returning a value.

Leaving these aside, here's a straightforward way to achieve it.

```
public static void checkAdapterNameOrSetDefaultValue(Optional<Device> device) {
    if (device.isPresent()) {
        final Optional<Socket> optionalSocket = device.get().getSocket();
        if (optionalSocket.isPresent()) {
            final Socket socket = optionalSocket.get();
            if (socket.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
                socket.setAdapter(Optional.of(new Adapter("DDD"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A fancy version would be

```
device.flatMap(Device::getSocket).ifPresent(socket -> {
    if (socket.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
        socket.setAdapter(Optional.of(new Adapter("DDD")));
    }
});
```

> is it possible to wrap the result from fancy version to the Adapter class?

Yes, but I am not a supporter of such things.

```
public static Optional<Adapter> checkAdapterNameOrSetDefaultValue(Optional<Device> device) {
    final Adapter defaultAdapter = new Adapter("DDD");

    return Optional.of(device
            .flatMap(Device::getSocket)
            .map(d -> {
                if (d.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
                    d.setAdapter(Optional.of(defaultAdapter));
                    return defaultAdapter;
                }
                return d.getAdapter().get();
            })
            .orElseGet(() -> defaultAdapter));
}
```

Comment: allways ready to go :). I know that is not good practice but I inherited this part of the code and I don't have anything to say.

Comment: is it possible to wrap the result from `fancy version` to the Adapter class? I am asking because I cannot change the signature of the method under any circumstances.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a monster but works perfectly. Like always, thanks for a fast response.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko if something like a `defaultAdapter` exists wouldn't it be better to set it within the `Socket` itself. OK maybe he doesn't have access to the class.